# C++ read memory crash

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to read memory in a different process, but every time I run the script, it crashes. [Windows 7 32-bit]

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int canJump;


int main()
{
    //DWORD oldProtect;
    //VirtualProtect((LPVOID)0x04565020, sizeof(unsigned int), PAGE_READONLY, &oldProtect);

    while(1)
    {
        canJump = *(unsigned int*)0x04565020;

        if(!paused)
        {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) && canJump == 0)
                cout << "here" << endl;
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F9))
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I looked into VirtualProtect (as you can see), but it did nothing. :(

Comment: "crashes"? Any meaningful error messages?

Comment: You can't access another processes memory all willy–nilly like that. Think about what would happen if the OS allowed that.

Comment: Avoid mutable data being shared across processes.

Comment: Yes I know that, Captain Oblivious.  I tried VirtualProtect already. :(

Comment: _*BUT!*_ did you try [`VirtualProtectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx)? Dun dun dun!

Comment: Just now I did, and it didn't work.  I don't see how it would help anyway.

Comment: What's the idea reading an address by a random hex number? Or is this some windows magic number 0x04565020?

Comment: _" I don't see how it would help anyway"_ - It's unfortunate that you didn't take the time to research `VirtualProtectEx` because that's likely what you want. If it didn't work you're either using it wrong or you haven't explained what you want to do well enough.

Comment: Unless you'll run your code on *Windows 3.11* or earlier, you're going to need to research inter process communication.

Comment: ... Oookay.

1) I didn't understand how the "Ex" will help me very much because I already know the address
2) @roeland: Unless you'll help me, there's no reason to comment anyway.

Comment: Hey Captain, I figured it out using ReadProcessMemory.  I'll add a comment with a solution.

Comment: @Nyero `ReadProcessMemory` and friends are there mainly to implement debuggers. Can you add a short explanation as of why you need to read that memory (and how you get that pointer)? Depending on the problem there are a few ways to communicate between processes, like named pipes or (since you're on Windows) sending messages to a window of another process.

Comment: You say that you already know the address... But how?  Especially with address layout randomization in effect... Or have you disabled all of the security features?

Comment: Has nobody ever used cheat engine?  You say these things almost as if they are impossible, and yet they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're using code intended for an internal hack, in an external hack.

`int main()` indicates this is an external hack and you're targetting an external project

`canJump = *(unsigned int*)0x04565020;` is code you would normally see in an internal hack.  This line is de-referencing an address to get it's value and store it in canJump.  Your program is external to the target process, therefore you cannot de-reference memory from an external process.  Your current code is de-referencing local memory.

To solve your problem, you must either convert this to an internal DLL which you inject or re-write everything as an external hack.  If you make it an external hack, you must use ToolHelp32Snapshot(), OpenProcess(), ReadProcessMemory() and WriteProcessMemory() to achieve your goal.